# How to get style from click event target?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-material

In angular material table, there is 24px padding-left on first cell:

```
td.mat-cell:first-of-type, td.mat-footer-cell:first-of-type, th.mat-header-cell:first-of-type {
    padding-left: 24px;
}
```

How can i get it? `ev.target.style.paddingLeft` is empty.

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x8p3x2?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.ts)

Comment: I dont see any `padding-left` property in your CSS

Comment: it is angular component, check the element in dev-tool

Comment: You can use [offsetWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetWidth). From the link: _Typically, offsetWidth is a measurement in pixels of the element's CSS width, including any borders, padding, and vertical scrollbars (if rendered)_

Comment: it is give me 78, since when i click in the end i get event x grater the 78.

Comment: The element itself does not have the `padding-left: 24px;` defined. It is getting the value from the classes that get applied to it. If properties are applied to the element, you could use `ev.srcElement.style` to get the values. The way suggested by @Mike would be the best approach in this case.

Comment: @Sachin Gupta i don't get any solution , the width need to be 102px.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `window.getComputedStyle()` method is used to retrieve the current, actual, properties of an element.
`window.getComputedStyle(myElement).paddingLeft` will give you the actual left padding of your element (with 'px' attached at the end).
In order to compute the element's width + left padding, use the following:

```
+window.getComputedStyle(myElement).paddingLeft.slice(0, -2) + 
+window.getComputedStyle(myElement).width.slice(0, -2);
```

If the width is fixed and never changes , just use `myElement.width` instead of `getComputerStyle()`;

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve what you want by passing the DOM element as a template parameter:

```html
<th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef #parameter (click)="cellClick($event, parameter)" > No. </th>
```

```js
cellClick(ev: MouseEvent, element: HTMLElement) {
 console.log(element.offsetWidth);
}
```

Comment: It is gives me the same result - 78px.

Comment: ev.target is  the element.

Comment: I am looking at your stackblitz and it gives the result 102px (with a large window size)